# Set theory problem on existence of functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

May I verify if my proof to the b/m claim is correct? Thank you!

Let $\mathbb{N}^{+}= \mathbb{N}-\{0\}.$ Suppose $h: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^+$ is a function. For each $m\in \mathbb{N}, $ let $h_m:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}^+$  be the function defined as follows: $\forall n \in \mathbb{N} [h_m(n)=H(m,n)].$ Prove there is a function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^+$ such that for each $m\in \mathbb{N},$ there exists $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq k[h_m(n)| f(n) ].$

Proof: Fix $n\in \mathbb{N}.$ Let $\phi(n):\forall m\in \mathbb{N} \exists r\in\mathbb{N}^+ [\forall j<m: H(j,n)| r$$]$. $\phi(0)$ is vacuously true. Suppose $\phi(m)$ is true, i.e. $\exists r\in \mathbb{N}^+ [\forall j\leq m: H(j,n)|r ].$ Let $r '=rH(m+1,n).$ Then $\phi(m+1)$ is true.

Define $G: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^+$ by $G(m,n) = min\{r\in \mathbb{N}^+: \forall j\leq m[H(n,j)|r ]\}.$ Fix $m \in \mathbb{N}.$ Let $ \omega(n): \forall n\in \mathbb{N}\exists r\in \mathbb{N}^+[\forall j \leq n:G(j,m)|r].$ Then $\omega(n) $ is true.( the proof is similar to that of $\phi(n)).$

Finally, define $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}^+$ by $f(k) = min\{r\in \mathbb{N}^+: \forall j\leq k[G(j,k) | r]\}.$ Fix $k\in \mathbb{N}.$ $\forall n \geq k, G(k,n)|f(n) \implies H(k,n)| f(n) \implies h_k(n) | f(n).$ Hence, given $m \in \mathbb{N},$ let $m=k. (qed)$

Comment: Can't you just set $f(n)=\prod_{m=0}^n H(m,n)$? That would work with $k=m$ for each $m$.

Comment: Splendid! I thought too complicatedly ><